# Uncorrelated implies independence?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence, correlation

Let $X\sim b(1,p)$ and $Y\sim b(1,q)$, in other words, $X$ and $Y$ are in Bernoulli distribution.
Question: If $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, does it imply $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

These are my steps:
$E(X)=p$ and $E(Y)=q$

Since $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated
$\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y)&=0\\
E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)&=0\\
E(XY)&=pq\\
\sum_{x}  \sum_{y}\ xy \cdot p(x,y) &= pq\ \\
p(1,1) &= pq
\end{align}$

Since $P_{X}(1)=p$, then
$\begin{align}
P(1,0)+P(1,1) &= p\\
P(1,0) &= p-qp \\
&= p(1-q)
\end{align}$

For the same reason, $P(0,1)=q(1-p)$
Then $P(0,0)=1-pq-p(1-q)-q(1-p)=(1-p)(1-q)$

Since $p(1,1)$ is known, the remaining 3 probabilities $p(x,y)$ is also determined and equal to $p_{X}(x) \cdot p_{Y}(y)$
Therefore, in this case, $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated and independent.

Am I right for this proof?

Comment: The other summands are $0\cdot 0\cdot p(0,0)=0; \  0\cdot 1\cdot p(0,1)=0; \ 1\cdot 0\cdot p(1,0)=0$. So you cannot deduce what are the values of $p(x,y)$.

Comment: Thanks for leaving comment, I have clarified the how to find $P(x,y)$

Comment: Your reasoning seems right now.

Comment: Beware: uncorrelated does mean independent in this case, but not in general.